# Silex - app->json() returning integer data as strings

Tags: php, mysql, json, silex

I just started working with Silex to help me build a restful api that returns data from my MySQL database.  Previously when working with php and mysql I noticed that MySQL would return integers as strings inside my `json_encode()` function.  It would put quotes around all my integer values.  The only way I was able to fix this was to pass `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` into the `json_encode` function:

```
return json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Worked lovely for what I needed.  Now that I'm using silex I've been using it's built-in json function to return values from my controllers.  I noticed I'm having the same problem with the integers getting returned as strings with quotes around them.

```
$app->get('/suppliers', function () use ($app) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM suppliers";
    $suppliers = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql);

    return $app->json(array('suppliers' => $suppliers));
});
```

Suppliers have a `supplier_id` field that is an integer, yet it is being returned as string in the json data.  I tried passing `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` into the `$app->json()` function after my array but would get an `InvalidArguementException`.

I did figure out instead of using the `$app->json()` function I could just use `json_encode()` php function and it would work. Like so:

```
$app->get('/suppliers', function () use ($app) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM suppliers";
    $suppliers = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql);

    //return $app->json(array('suppliers' => $suppliers));
    return json_encode(array('suppliers' => $suppliers), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
});
```

Is there any reason NOT to do it this way instead of using the silex `$app->json()` function?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: _“Suppliers have a supplier_id field that is an integer, yet it is being returned as string in the json data”_ – and that is causing which problem where and how, so that there’s need to fix something here? // There are situations where transferring integer values as strings is actually preferable – take Facebook’s API for example, their user ids “looked” like integers for a long time, but with the user base growing, that easily caused problems on platforms that had a lower max integer value – leading to them being converted to floats, thereby loosing precision, and becoming unusable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$app->json(...)` returns response `JsonResponse`. You can manually create this type of response and set encoding options.

```
$app->get('/suppliers', function () use ($app) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM suppliers";
    $suppliers = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql);

    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse();
    $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    $response->setData(array('suppliers' => $suppliers));

    return $response;
});
```

or set allready encoded content

```
$app->get('/suppliers', function () use ($app) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM suppliers";
    $suppliers = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql);

    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse();
    $response->setContent(json_encode(array('suppliers' => $suppliers), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));

    return $response;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

try with setEncodingOptions

```
return $app->json($var, Response::HTTP_OK)->setEncodingOptions(JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: and to make it api wide I suggest adding it to the middleware with `$app->after(function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    if (0 === strpos($response->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
        $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
});`