# Develop a rest api using Silex framework

Tags: php, json, rest, silex

I'm starting to develop a rest api using silex. It's my first api!

**What i've done:**

**Update:** 
Code improved with the tip of Federic . Addition of Use Symfony JsonResponse. Not working for now.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

// init Silex app
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

//configure database connection
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'dbname' => 'db',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
));

$app->get('/apps', function () use ($app){
    $sql = "select apps.id, apps.guid, apps.title, clients.client, countries.country, langs.lang, apps.active from apps
            inner join countries on apps.id_country = countries.id
            inner join clients on clients.id = apps.id_client
            inner join langs on langs.id = apps.id_lang
            order by apps.created_at desc";
    $results = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql);


        $response['status'] = array(
            'code' => 200,
            'message' => 'OK'
        );

        $response['data'] = $results;

    //return $app->json($response);
    $jsonResponse = new JsonResponse($response);
    $jsonResponse->setEncodingOptions(JsonReponse::DEFAULT_ENCODING_OPTIONS | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    return $jsonResponse;
});


$app->run();
```

What it return?

```
{"status":{"code":200,"message":"OK"},"data":[{"id":"2","guid":"a8559e9b-d850-4964-b672-335a87fe9e8b","title":"Coverdine Plus Light","client":"Servier","country":"England","lang":"English","active":"1"},{"id":"1","guid":"4f242e9d-c041-4c79-bc82-b62604de403c","title":"Coverdine","client":"Servier","country":"England","lang":"English","active":"0"}]}
```

How can i use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` to improve human read of my json object?

Comment: Instead of prettyprinting your response, you should use a tool like Postman for testing your api, it formats the response for you for readability.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142601/silex-app-json-returning-integer-data-as-strings/35161207#35161207

Comment: Max P. - Thanks for link. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `$app->json($response);`, use `JsonResponse` instead. You can set `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag with his `setEncodingOptions` method.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

// ...
$jsonResponse = new JsonResponse($response);
$jsonResponse->setEncodingOptions(JsonResponse::DEFAULT_ENCODING_OPTIONS | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

return $jsonResponse;
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but it gives me this error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'JsonReponse' not found in

Comment: have you missed `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;`?

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
...
require_once(__DIR__ .'/../vendor/autoload.php');
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

...
$response = $sth->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $app->json($response, Response::HTTP_OK)->setEncodingOptions(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have had this difficulty, and after much research I found the function: do_dump, [click here](https://github.com/burbridgeconsulting/wpi-muddyhare88/blob/master/do_dump.php) to see it in github.

To use it, just do this:

```
$var = json_decode('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}');
do_dump($var);
```